# Matlab: conv(u,v) but that sums 'u' and 'v'?

Tags: matlab, sum

Is there any function in Matlab like conv(u,v) but that sums up 'u(x)' and 'v(x)' instead of multiplying them?

Imagine:

```
u(x) = 66*(x-6)
v(x) = 6*(x-9)
```

Applying this "wanted function"...

```
sum = wantedfunction(u,v)
```

So,

```
sum(x) = 66*(x-6) + 6*(x-9)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Convolution involves "flip", "shift", and vector inner product.  Your result doesn't suggest either "flip" or "shift".  Why can't you just use the `plus` function, and how is this related to `conv`?

Comment: but i need to add functions, not numbers... Does 'add' function works for functions too ?

Comment: It works just like `conv` does... on vectors (which might be the result of functions) or symbolic expressions.

Comment: If you showed some sample code using `conv`, we could then tell you how to perform addition instead.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can do what you are asking for using anonymous functions:

```
u = @( x ) ( 66 * (x - 6) );
v = @( x ) (  6 * (x - 9) );
w = @( x ) ( u(x) + v(x) );
```

This makes `w` the "sum" function you wanted - if I understood your question correctly.

Example: after I keyed in the above, I found

```
w(1:5)
```

Gave

```
 -378 -306 -234 -162  -90
```

It's possible I completely missed the point of your question - if so, please leave a comment.

Comment: I understood it the same way. Dunno what this has to do with `conv` but yeah, sounds correct to me

Comment: I think the original poster wants to pass `u` and `v` as arguments: `w = @(u, v, x) ( u(x) + v(x) );`, and then `w(u,v,1:5)`

Comment: Yes, that's it Floris :) Can I display the w(x) for w = @( x ) ( u(x) + v(x) ); ?  Last question..

Comment: @JoãoFilipe - what do you mean "can I display"? Do you want to see the values, or do you want to see `w(x) = (66 + 6) * x - (66 * 6 + 6 * 9)`? The former is easy - the latter _may_ be possible with the symbolic math toolbox (which I don't have, unfortunately…)

Comment: @JoãoFilipe If you have access to the symbolic math toolbox you should be able to do that - if you do not, then I don't know of a way to achieve this. And since I don't have the sym toolbox myself, I can't help you any further, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If by "conv" function you mean convolution then the equivalent of that for your case is simply adding two functions you want and then multiply them by delta(your desired spacing on x axis) and then sum over that, gives your function. Still you need to iterate this process by a "for" loop for different delays.